# PANIC: ANDROID_SDK_HOME is defined but could not find Nexus_5_API_23_x86.ini file

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, android-sdk

When I try to run the emulator on Android studio it prints

```
PANIC: ANDROID_SDK_HOME is defined but could not find Nexus_5_API_23_x86.ini file in $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd
Note: The environment variable $ANDROID_SDK_HOME is set, and the emulator uses that variable to locate AVDs.
This may result in the emulator failing to start if it cannot find the AVDs in the folder pointed to by the
given environment variable.
ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/home/lavi/android-sdk
```

Note: avd is searched in the order of `$ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd and $HOME/.android/avd`

Please tell me steps:
How to move the files and set sdk in ubuntu 14.04?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got the exact same issue recently. I was on MacOSX but the result was the same. I figured out that Android Studio was not launched correctly from the "Dock" with the set of environment variables that it was supposed to. I suggest that you lunch it thru a command line and see how it goes.

Basically "$HOME/.android/avd" is not used for some obscure reason (and the .ini file which is there is not found)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should set `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` directly.

```
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=~/.android/avd
```

If that doesn't work, you can try `ln -s ~/.android/avd ~/Android/sdk/avd`